# Вывод чисел прописью в PHP (1 - один,15 - пятнадцать,...)

Tags: php, jquery

```
$number = radn (1,150);
```

Есть случайное число. Как мне его вывести в виде текста? То есть например рандом дал **45**.

Должен вывести: **Сорок пять**

Знаю это сложновато, помогите. Спасибо заранее.

Comment: Самый оптимальный вариант,на мой взгляд,создать массив,где будут храниться названия чисел ,затем при формировании числа ,находить его соответствие и выводить.

Comment: https://habrahabr.ru/post/53210/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Просто используйте расширение Intl и все, ничего сложного.

```
<?php
$result = (new \MessageFormatter('ru-RU', '{n, spellout}'))->format(['n' => 45]);
echo $result;  // сорок пять
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно поступить следующим образом

```
<?php
  //допустимый диапазон чисел 0 .. 999999
  //число прописью
  function write_number_in_words ($num, $genus = 'masculinum')
  {
    //разряд: единицы, десятки, сотни, тысячи
    $cur_order = "единицы";
    $cur_thousands_order = "единицы";
    $next_digit = "";
    if($num == 0)
      return " 00";
    $num = strval($num);
    $limit = strlen($num) - 1;
    for($i = $limit; $i >= 0; $i--)
    {
      //тысячный разряд
      if($cur_order == "тысячи")
      {
        //сотни
        if($cur_thousands_order == "сотни")
        {
          $str = write_units_hundreds($num[$i]).$str;
        }
        //десятки
        if($cur_thousands_order == "десятки")
        {
          $str = write_units_tens($num[$i], $next_digit).$str;
          $cur_thousands_order = "сотни";
          $next_digit = '';
        }
        //единицы
        if($cur_thousands_order == "единицы")
        {
          if($num[$i == 0 ? 0 : $i - 1] == "1")
          {
            $next_digit = $num[$i];
            $str = " тысяч".$str;
          }
          else
            $str = write_units_thousands_units($num[$i]).$str;
          $cur_thousands_order = "десятки";
        }
      }
      //сотни
      if($cur_order == "сотни")
      {
        $str = write_units_hundreds($num[$i]).$str;
        $cur_order = "тысячи";
      }
      //десятки
      if($cur_order == "десятки")
      {
        $str = write_units_tens($num[$i], $next_digit).$str;
        $cur_order = "сотни";
        $next_digit = '';
      }
      //единицы
      if($cur_order == "единицы")
      {
        if($num[$i == 0 ? 0 : $i - 1] == "1")
          $next_digit = $num[$i];
        else
          $str = write_units($num[$i], $genus);
        $cur_order = "десятки";
      }
    }
    return($str);
  }

  //принадлежит функции write_number_in_words
  //преобразует десятки
  function write_units_tens ($tens, $next_digit)
  {
    $tens .= $next_digit;
    if($tens == 2) $str_tens = " двадцать";
    if($tens == 3) $str_tens = " тридцать";
    if($tens == 4) $str_tens = " сорок";
    if($tens == 5) $str_tens = " пятьдесят";
    if($tens == 6) $str_tens = " шестьдесят";
    if($tens == 7) $str_tens = " семьдесят";
    if($tens == 8) $str_tens = " восемьдесят";
    if($tens == 9) $str_tens = " девяносто";
    if($tens == 10) $str_tens = " десять";
    if($tens == 11) $str_tens = " одиннадцать";
    if($tens == 12) $str_tens = " двенадцать";
    if($tens == 13) $str_tens = " тринадцать";
    if($tens == 14) $str_tens = " четырнадцать";
    if($tens == 15) $str_tens = " пятнадцать";
    if($tens == 16) $str_tens = " шестнадцать";
    if($tens == 17) $str_tens = " семнадцать";
    if($tens == 18) $str_tens = " восемнадцать";
    if($tens == 19) $str_tens = " девятнадцать";
    return $str_tens;
  }

  //принадлежит функции write_number_in_words
  //преобразует сотни
  function write_units_hundreds ($hundreds)
  {
    $str_hundreds = "";
    if($hundreds == 1) $str_hundreds = " сто";
    if($hundreds == 2) $str_hundreds = " двести";
    if($hundreds == 3) $str_hundreds = " триста";
    if($hundreds == 4) $str_hundreds = " четыреста";
    if($hundreds == 5) $str_hundreds = " пятьсот";
    if($hundreds == 6) $str_hundreds = " шестьсот";
    if($hundreds == 7) $str_hundreds = " семьсот";
    if($hundreds == 8) $str_hundreds = " восемьсот";
    if($hundreds == 9) $str_hundreds = " девятьсот";
    return $str_hundreds;
  }

  //принадлежит функции write_number_in_words
  //преобразует единицы тысячного разряда
  function write_units_thousands_units ($hundreds)
  {
    $str_hundreds = "";
    if($hundreds == 0) $str_hundreds = " тысяч";
    if($hundreds == 1) $str_hundreds = " одна тысяча";
    if($hundreds == 2) $str_hundreds = " две тысячи";
    if($hundreds == 3) $str_hundreds = " три тысячи";
    if($hundreds == 4) $str_hundreds = " четыре тысячи";
    if($hundreds == 5) $str_hundreds = " пять тысяч";
    if($hundreds == 6) $str_hundreds = " шесть тысяч";
    if($hundreds == 7) $str_hundreds = " семь тысяч";
    if($hundreds == 8) $str_hundreds = " восемь тысяч";
    if($hundreds == 9) $str_hundreds = " девять тысяч";
    return $str_hundreds;
  }

  //принадлежит функции write_number_in_words
  //преобразует единицы
  function write_units ($units, $genus='masculinum')
  {
    $str_units = "";
    if($genus == 'masculinum')
    {
       if($units == 1) $str_units = " один";
       if($units == 2) $str_units = " два";
    }
    if($genus == 'femininum')
    {
       if($units == 1) $str_units = " одна";
       if($units == 2) $str_units = " две";

    }
    if($units == 3) $str_units = " три";
    if($units == 4) $str_units = " четыре";
    if($units == 5) $str_units = " пять";
    if($units == 6) $str_units = " шесть";
    if($units == 7) $str_units = " семь";
    if($units == 8) $str_units = " восемь";
    if($units == 9) $str_units = " девять";
    return $str_units;
  }
  echo write_number_in_words(45);
```